# org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleArchive: Unable to create archive directory

Tags: windows-7, spring-roo

googling I gound that this error is shown when windows can't run a .bat
I'm getting this when I'm running `roo` comand in my workspace.

OS -> windows 7, 32 bits
jdk -> jdk1.6.0_22
roo -> spring-roo-1.1.0.RELEASE

The hole error message is:

```
ERROR: Unable to create system bundle directory.
ERROR: org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleArchive: Unable to create archive directory.
```

Repeated hundreds of times.
I followed all [these steps](http://www.springsource.org/roo/start), but anyway I'm getting the error. Does anybody know why??

I read another similar problem, which was solved moving from OpenJDK to JDK 1.6. But I have already JDK 1.6

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I did not have the aprropiate rights to the installation folder of roo. Then I changed my rights and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I also have same issue today on windows 7, 64 bit. after spending some time solved it.

1. Goto %ROO_HOME%/bin ( for me ROO_HOME = C:\Program Files\springsource\spring-roo-1.1.5.RELEASE)
2. Right Click Roo.bat and select option 'Run As administrator' from pop-up.
   ----------------------------------OR-----------------------------
3. In Run box ( last option in Start button pop-up), type cmd
4. Instead of hitting Enter, use CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER. Click yes on pop-up box
5. Command prompt with Administrative Properties will come up, type ROO and it comes up.
   ( C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you are running as a 'normal' user yet the internal Felix OSGI container, by default, tries to create a felix-cache directory in the working directory.

Two solutions which are probably better than simply elevating your permissions:

1. Set the org.osgi.framework.storage system property (e.g. -Dorg.osgi.framework.storage=C:\Users\MyUsername)
2. Run it from a different working directory, one that you have write permissions for